# get Zero-width non-joiner (&zwnj;) with innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a `&zwnj;` with `innerHTML`

The output should be

```
This div contains a zero-width‌&zwnj;non-joiner, a non-breaking&nbsp;space &amp; an ampersand
```

But the output is:

```
This div contains a zero-width‌non-joiner, a non-breaking&nbsp;space &amp; an ampersand
```

How can I get the `&zwnj;`?

```js
alert(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML)
```

```html
<div>This div contains a zero-width&zwnj;non-joiner, a non-breaking&nbsp;space &amp; an ampersand</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yst1Lanv/

Comment: You do get the character itself, which can be proved by parsing the text with `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: what happened to the fiddle? can't play around with the snippet on site

Comment: @Antony example please!?

Comment: @Xaver [the documentation has examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for it using its unicode `\u200c`. Then replace it with `&zwnj;` string.

```js
alert(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML.replace(/\u200c/g, '&zwnj;'))
```

```html
<div>This div contains a zero-width&zwnj;non-joiner, a non-breaking&nbsp;space &amp; an ampersand</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your character is in the extracted (`innerHTML`) text, just not encoded as its HTML entity.

If you want you can replace the character with its entity:

```js
alert(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML.replace(/‌/g, '&zwnj;'));
```

```html
<div>This div contains a zero-width&zwnj;non-joiner, a non-breaking&nbsp;space &amp; an ampersand</div>
```

Yong Quan posted some nicer code than me, if you want your app to be more maintainable use the unicode. My regex above is pretty confusing, this is easier to read:

```
.replace(/\u200c/g, '&zwnj;')
```

Comment: ok, this works but what about other characters like `&zwj;`? Do I have to replace them all "manually"?

Comment: @Xaver it depends why you want the text returned to encode them as HTML entities. Sounds like it's a non-problem.

Comment: haha, thought this is a special character as others like `&nbsp;` or `&amp;` work as expected